# pip3 install error after migrated from intel iMac to M1 iMac

Tags: python, pip

I migrated all of my data from my old Intel iMac to my new M1 iMac and I thought that only files will be transferred. 
 After migration, I realized that softwares including python and R were also transferred.
But the python packages were not transferred, so I had to reinstall them with pip. Some packages like numpy and scipy worked perfectly fine, and other packages (Py2bit and pyBigWig) don't work.
 I tried uninstalling python and upgraded it to python 3.10.2, and also tried duplicating Terminal and reopening it with Rosetta, but I still get the following error message.

```
> pip3 install py2bit
Collecting py2bit
  Using cached py2bit-0.3.0.tar.gz (16 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Skipping wheel build for py2bit, due to binaries being disabled for it.
Installing collected packages: py2bit
  Running setup.py install for py2bit ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Running setup.py install for py2bit did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [44 lines of output]
      /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py:732: UserWarning: Usage of dash-separated 'description-file' will not be supported in future versions. Please use the underscore name 'description_file' instead
        warnings.warn(
      /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py:275: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'classifier'
        warnings.warn(msg)
      running install
      /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
        warnings.warn(
      running build
      running build_py
      running egg_info
      writing py2bit.egg-info/PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to py2bit.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
      writing top-level names to py2bit.egg-info/top_level.txt
      reading manifest file 'py2bit.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
      reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
      adding license file 'LICENSE.txt'
      running build_ext
      building 'py2bit' extension
      lib2bit/2bit.c:96:25: warning: comparison of integers of different signs: 'int' and 'uint32_t' (aka 'unsigned int') [-Wsign-compare]
          for(offset=0; offset<remainder; offset++) {
                        ~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~
      lib2bit/2bit.c:311:20: warning: comparison of integers of different signs: 'uint32_t' (aka 'unsigned int') and 'int' [-Wsign-compare]
              if(maskIdx != -1 && start + i + 4 >= maskStart) {
                 ~~~~~~~ ^  ~~
      2 warnings generated.
      lib2bit/2bit.c:96:25: warning: comparison of integers of different signs: 'int' and 'uint32_t' (aka 'unsigned int') [-Wsign-compare]
          for(offset=0; offset<remainder; offset++) {
                        ~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~
      lib2bit/2bit.c:311:20: warning: comparison of integers of different signs: 'uint32_t' (aka 'unsigned int') and 'int' [-Wsign-compare]
              if(maskIdx != -1 && start + i + 4 >= maskStart) {
                 ~~~~~~~ ^  ~~
      2 warnings generated.
      py2bit.c:35:17: warning: incompatible pointer types initializing 'pyTwoBit_t *' with an expression of type 'TwoBit *' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
          pyTwoBit_t *pytb = self->tb;
                      ^      ~~~~~~~~
      1 warning generated.
      py2bit.c:35:17: warning: incompatible pointer types initializing 'pyTwoBit_t *' with an expression of type 'TwoBit *' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
          pyTwoBit_t *pytb = self->tb;
                      ^      ~~~~~~~~
      1 warning generated.
      ld: warning: ignoring file /usr/local/Cellar/llvm/9.0.0_1/lib/clang/9.0.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.osx.a, missing required architecture arm64 in file /usr/local/Cellar/llvm/9.0.0_1/lib/clang/9.0.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.osx.a (2 slices)
      ld: in '/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib/libunwind.dylib', building for macOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-x86_64
      clang-9: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
      error: command '/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> py2bit

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

Comment: You are mixing different CPU architectures _building for macOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-x86_64_.

Comment: Maurice, thank you so much!
I didn't know what to do so I tried to uninstall and reinstall homebrew, but then realized that the cause was my .bash_profile. The mac migration system migrated my previous .bash_profile file as well and it was doing something bad apparently. Now everything is solved!